# Oracle SSO logout issues

Tags: oracle, cookies

I'm implementing Oracle SSO on an application. The login works just fine but I'm facing an issue with logout. The main issue is when I logout and then try to login again with a different account, it throws me to an error page. However if I login with the same account again, it works fine.

After checking the complete flow step by step I’ve noticed that among multiple session cookies, Oracle SSO creates a certain cookie ‘ORA_OSFS_SESSION’ on login that does not get deleted with logout. When I manually delete this cookie but leave all others, all works fine.

Any idea why this might be happening and why this cookie does not get deleted on logout from my application?

Comment: Did you get any solution of this problem? I am facing same issue right now